# In my pedometer application, why doesn't my NSTimer stop when I want it to?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Please help me, friends. I have finished making a steps counter. My problem now is that my timer starts with the accelerometer, but it doesn't stop when the accelerometer stops.(Pedometer is an application where the user can count his\her steps. With this information, the user can count his total calories consumed, and the total elapsed time.) The problem is that my timer is not working properly. Please help me out.

here is code

```
if (  fabsf(acceleration.y) > progressAsInt ) {
        steps++;
        timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(.01) target:self selector:@selector(timepassed) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


        NSString *stepcount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", steps];
        [stepstaken setText:stepcount];

        //it's for the MPH speed calculation formula changes can be happen
        /*formula mph= miles/hour
         0.5miles
         10minutes = 10/60 hours = 0.1667
         mph=0.5/0.1667*/

        mspeed = (TotalDistance *3600)/60;
        //mspeed =(steps*steplength)/63360*60;
       NSString *speed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.2f",mspeed];
        [mSpeed setText:speed];


        //this for calculation of miles
        TotalDistance = (steps *steplength)/1500;
        NSString *distance =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%5.3f",TotalDistance];
        [miles setText:distance];


       if (steps%20==0)
        {
            //And this for calorie calculation
            cal++;

            NSString *cal1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cal];
            [calorie setText:cal1];
        }else{
           [timer1 invalidate];

       }        
}
```

Comment: Maybe consider editing your old question instead of asking new ones: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171716/pedometer-app-in-iphone
Also, please accept answers on your old questions.

Comment: @Harishdy007: @Eiko is right, you really should edit the old question.  Since it didn't have any answers though, I went ahead and just deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the indentation of your code to match its structure.  It should be pretty obvious to you now that the `else` is in the wrong place if you are trying to invalidate the timer when the acceleration is below a threshold.